# Visual C# 2008 Express designer not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

This problem suddenly arose after I took a break from my work. When I went to click on the designer for one of my forms, a message box was shown like this:

I'm not allowed images yet so I will describe:
The form title states: Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition
In the main body there is an error icon and then a paragraph of text saying:

```
Method not found: 'Int32
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsRunningDocTableEvents2.OnAft
erAttributeChangeEx(UInt32, UInt32,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierachy, UInt32, System.String,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierachy, UInt32,
System.String)'.
```

Now after restarting the IDE several times and trying again it still throws this error. I could not find anything on Google that covers this issue. Could somebody please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: check 1.4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsxteam/archive/2008/01/30/known-issues-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-sdk-1.0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that occurs within Visual Studio and has nothing to do with the user.

**Solution**:
Reinstall Visual Studio... Unfortunately.